# Saving part of a video with FFmpeg using C

Tags: java, c, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, video-editing

I am creating a simple video editing application using Java, JNI, C, and FFmpeg. The UI is being designed in Java and I am talking with FFmpeg from a C file using JNI. Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way I should go about saving part of a video file using FFmpeg? I am allowing the users to choose parts of the video to save and what I am thinking as of right now is to basically loop through all of the packets and decode each frame (if need to encode to a different format) then save the frame to a file. All the while seeking to different parts of the video based on the users start and stop sections of their crops. If this doesn't make sense I would be glad to clear it up. Any ideas are much appreciated as I am just looking to create the most efficient and correct way to go about doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xuggler?  It will do all for you without you having to figure out the jni bindings.

Comment: The problem with that is I am doing this project on Android and I have looked at Xuggler but didnt attempt to get it working on Android (If possible at all). Do you happen to know if this would be possible? Or how I would go about doing it? All I really need is an example of how to properly do this on the C/C++ side because I have the JNI bindings working fine to be able to call the C code from the Java side. Thanks for the answer though hopefully I will get something going soon...